# ScalingFunctions->Reverse in ListPlot not compatible with Epilog

Tags: plotting, graphics

My question is rather to the point; I'm trying to reverse the x-axis on a ListPlot that has some objects drawn in it with Epilog. I looked around a bit and I found that the easiest method is to use ScalingFunctions->Reverse, which indeed neatly reverses the x-axis, but somehow ends up making the Epilog disappear. Does anyone know why this happens/how I can fix this?

Some sample code to illustrate it:

```
xs = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
ys = xs^2;
{ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys}],(*ScalingFunctions\[Rule]{"Reverse",
  Identity},*)
  Epilog -> {{Directive[{Thick, Black}], 
     Line[{{0.4, 0}, {0.4, 1}}]}}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{xs, ys}], 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, 
  Epilog -> {{Directive[{Thick, Black}], 
     Line[{{0.4, 0}, {0.4, 1}}]}}]}
```

[image]

Comment: the reverse has effectively negated the coordinate system so you need to make your line `Line[{{-0.4, 0}, {-0.4, 1}}]`  (sorry more of a work around than an explanation)

Comment: ScalingFunctions -> Reverse just renames the ticks. If you increased your PlotRange to still include the right side of the x-axis I'm sure you'd see your epilog call.

Comment: @user6014 it does quite a bit more than that. It transforms the data, fixes the `PlotRange`, the `AxesOrigin`, and the ticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Epilog` has not disappeared, it just is not visible with the `PlotRange` generated by `ListPlot`, e.g.

```
In[23]:= Options[plot, {PlotRange, Epilog}]
(*Out[23]= {PlotRange -> {{-1., 0}, {0, 1.}}, 
 Epilog -> {{Directive[{Thickness[Large], GrayLevel[0]}], 
  Line[{{0.4, 0}, {0.4, 1}}]}}}*)
```

where `plot` is the one with the `ScalingFunctions`. The difficulty here is that `Epilog` and `Prolog` exist in the `Graphics` coordinate system, not the coordinate system your data is in. The workaround is to transform the coordinates used to the data coordinates, i.e.

```
Epilog -> {{Directive[{Thickness[Large], GrayLevel[0]}], 
  Line[{{-0.4, 0}, {-0.4, 1}}]}}}
```

[image]

Similarly for the other `ScalingFunctions`, too.