# Epilog isn't working

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to put an arrow to denote a point on a Plot

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{temp1, lum1}], Transpose[{temp2, lum2}], 
  Transpose[{temp3, lum3}], Transpose[{temp4, lum4}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Hue[First@#2/12], Hue[First@#2/15], Hue[First@#2/18], 
   Hue[First@#2/21]}, 
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{{4.2, 3.6}, {4.4, 3.6}}], 
   Text["text", {4.4, 3.6}, {4.4, 4}]}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 22], 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Green}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperatura Log T [K]", FontSize -> 22, Bold], 
   Style["Luminosidad Log L [\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(sol\)]\)]", 
    FontSize -> 22, Bold]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

but Epilog seems to not be working properly. The output is

[image]

while I'd expect to see an arrow pointing to the yellow point at (4.4,3.6)

Comment: does `Epilog -> {Arrow[{{-4.2, 3.6}, {-4.4, 3.6}}], 
   Text["text", {-4.4, 3.6}]}` give what you need?

Comment: Previous question [scaling functions not compatible with epilog in listplot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135836/) may be relevant

Comment: Actually @kglr advise did part of the job. Now the arrow is visible but not the text.

Comment: make sure you use `Text["text", {-4.4, 3.6}]`  not `Text["text", {-4.4, 3.6}, {-4.4,4}]` or `Text["text", {-4.4, 3.6}, {4.4,4}]`

Comment: @kglr Epilog -> {Arrow[{{-4.2, 3.6}, {-4.35, 3.6}}], 
  Text["ZAMS", {-4.4, 3.6}, {-10, -0}]} this was the only way to make it work. Do you know how to manage the FontSize?

Comment: `Text[Style["ZAMS", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]],  Offset[{5, 2},  {-4.4, 3.6}], {Left, Bottom}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{3.5, 4.4}, {100, 2}];

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{{-4.2, 3.6}, {-4.4, 3.6}}], 
   Text[Style["text", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], {-4.4, 3.6}, {Left, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

`Text[Style["text", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], {-4.4, 3.6}, {-1, -1}]` gives the same picture.

You can also use `Offset[{xprinterpoints, yprinterpoints}, {xpos,ypos}]` in the second argument of `Text` to specify the position. Using

```
  Text[Style["text", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], Offset[{15, 5}, {-4.4, 3.6}], {-1, - 1}]
```

above, we get

[image]

Using

```
Text[Style["text", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], Offset[{15, -5}, {-4.4, 3.6}], {-1, 1}]
```

gives

[image]

and

```
Text[Style["text", FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], Offset[{-25, 0}, {-4.4, 3.6}], {-1, -1}]
```

gives

[image]